# Will the deleted browser history be stored in File-system?

Tags: filesystem, firefox, browser

I would like to know if the history of urls i browse with my Firefox browser, which i have cleared, will be stored in the file system or not?

To be more clear, will the history be stored in some place in the hard-disk, even if the history is deleted from the browser menu(delete history option)?

If yes, Can i retrieve those details?

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately (I'm guessing you were hoping to recover?) this information is completely deleted when you clear it. The way linux filesystems (most of them, such as ext4) work, the data is actually deleted, though not **wiped**. You would not be able to retrieve this data yourself. Maybe someone who is an expert in file recovery could *potentially* recover the data.

There is an option for you to backup your history, but I would suggest you ask a new question for that (*if that is what you are hoping to do in the future, as you did not state it*).

Comment: Okay.. Thanks Roland for the info. Why i asked this qs is like i was able to get the name of many links which i browsed on my windows Machine (even after formatting my windows pc..) that doesnt mean, the full website, but i could get the name of the link..

Comment: I was able to get it from the Registry.. I dont exactly remember the path now.. it was some 5 years back..

Comment: I was able to do that on windows as well, but that was with internet explorer, and it is a rather tricky method they use, which is really an invasion of privacy, and a danger in that other applications can access the data (e.g. viruses/spyware).